# Add the gpg key used to sign the packages by running the following wget | gpg | tee >/dev/null command

Tags: networking, apt, kali-linux, gpg, tor

I was preparing my Kali Linux to run a Tor's Middle Relay. I was doing Tor Project's Repository configuration according to [this site](https://support.torproject.org/apt/tor-deb-repo/).

I made steps 1 and 2. The 3rd step was to add the gpg key used to sign the packages by running the following command:

```
sudo wget -qO- https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null
```

The problem is I don't understand what this command does and why it fails, even though I execute it with `sudo` permissions.

```
┌──(michal㉿kali)-[/usr/share/keyrings]
└─$ sudo wget -qO- https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null
[sudo] password for michal: tee: /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg: Permission denied
```

This part with `wget`, I understand. But I don't know what is happening after the tor repo gets downloaded to my vps.

```
┌──(michal㉿kali)-[/usr/share/keyrings]
└─$ ls -lah
total 176K
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Jan 28  2022 .
drwxr-xr-x 135 root root 4.0K Jan  3 18:09 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 8.5K Feb 25  2021 debian-archive-bullseye-automatic.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 8.6K Feb 25  2021 debian-archive-bullseye-security-automatic.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 2.4K Feb 25  2021 debian-archive-bullseye-stable.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 8.0K Feb 25  2021 debian-archive-buster-automatic.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 8.0K Feb 25  2021 debian-archive-buster-security-automatic.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 2.3K Feb 25  2021 debian-archive-buster-stable.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  55K Feb 25  2021 debian-archive-keyring.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  37K Feb 25  2021 debian-archive-removed-keys.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 7.3K Feb 25  2021 debian-archive-stretch-automatic.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 7.3K Feb 25  2021 debian-archive-stretch-security-automatic.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 2.3K Feb 25  2021 debian-archive-stretch-stable.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 2.3K Jan 25  2022 kali-archive-keyring.gpg
```

```
┌──(michal㉿kali)-[/usr/share/keyrings]
└─$ lsb_release -a                                                                                                                                         1 ⨯
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:        2022.4
Codename:       kali-rolling
```

Comment: You are executing the `wget` command with sudo, but it is the `tee` command that needs permission to write to the keyring directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's break down what's happening.  `sudo` is only being used to run `wget`, not the rest of the command.  What you did is functionally equivalent to:

```
# 1. Download a file and save as 'file.asc'
sudo wget -qO- https://d...E886DDD89.asc > file.asc

# 2. Dearmor that file (generates file.asc.gpg)
gpg --dearmor file.asc

# 3. Copy that file to /usr/share/keyrings
tee /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null <file.asc.gpg
```

So you see, you used `sudo` to download the file.  That doesn't really do much in this situation, except make `file.asc` owned by `root`.  In your case, the file is piped onto stdout, so `sudo` *really* doesn't do much.

Next, you used `gpg --dearmor`, which is fine.

Finally, you used `tee` to copy the contents of the file to your system.   This is the part that needs `root` permissions because you are writing to a `root`-owned directory.

The answer is to run `tee` with `sudo`.  Functionally this would look like:

```
# 1. Download a file and save as 'file.asc'
wget -qO- https://d...E886DDD89.asc > file.asc

# 2. Dearmor that file (generates file.asc.gpg)
gpg --dearmor file.asc

# 3. Copy that file to /usr/share/keyrings
sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null <file.asc.gpg
```

In your 1-liner, it would look like:

```
wget -qO- \
  https://deb...6DDD89.asc | \
  gpg --dearmor | \
  sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null
```

or

```
wget -qO- https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89.asc | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null
```

In fact, the reason we  `| tee /usr/share... >/dev/null` instead of the much simpler `>/usr/share...` is so we can prefix `tee` with `sudo`.

Comment: just  in case `sudo` need password, just run `sudo -v` (and validate with password) before running full command.

Comment: @Stewart Can you please add the pipe in the last piece of code you shared? The last 1-liner. There's a pipe missing before ```gpg --dearmor```. You've helped me a lot. I will accept this answer once this edit is made.

Comment: I understand this part ```sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg``` that the dearmored file is being saved as ```/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg``` but I don't understand this last part. ```>/dev/null``` What is ```/dev/null``` ? And why ```/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg``` file is being overwritten onto ```/dev/null```?

Comment: `tee <file>` reads stdin and writes to both stdout and to `<file>`.  We only care about file (we'd prefer silence on stdout), so `>/dev/null` simply redirects stdout to nowhere.  `<file>` is still written to.